# How to integrate greenDAO with JSON Jackson and handle many to many relation mapping

Tags: android, orm, greendao

Is there any best way to integrate JSON Jackson with greenDAO. Also, how to handle many to many relation mapping using greenDAO. I found that, we need to create a connecting table to have many to many mapping. Is there any example having all these features together.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in dao Generator file edit entity.ftl

and add necessary lines to integrate Jackson 
ie

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

and

```
@JsonProperty("Tag Name")
```

Thus you dont have to write any extra code for this.