# Integrating greenDAO and Jackson

Tags: android, jackson, greendao, greendao-generator

I am working on a project with an Android side and a backend, and for the JSON parsing I am using Jackson library on both sides.
Using Play 2.0 for the backend, Ebean is Jackson annotations friendly, but the problem is with GreenDAO, since GreenDAO uses code generation, I have to type again all the annotations every time I migrate the database.
I searched around and found only
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374306/how-to-integrate-greendao-with-json-jackson-and-handle-many-to-many-relation-map) but I can't find any template file.

I am using GreenDao 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that instead of adding the annotations in the Model itself, according to the [documentation of the modelling](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/modelling-entities/#Keep_sections)  you can use methods like `setCodeBeforeClass(String code)` and `codeBeforeField(String code)`to add the annotations,
for example in the Generator Module

```
schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault();

    Entity gItem= schema.addEntity("GrItem");
    gItem.setCodeBeforeClass("@JsonSerialize(using = ItemSerializer.class)"+"\n"+"@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)");
    gItem.addIdProperty().codeBeforeField("@JsonProperty(\"id\")");
```

thus every time you run the generator you can still generate the annotations with the code